# Column-wise Spearman Correlation between two data frames

Tags: r

I want to compute the column-wise Spearman correlation between two dataframes `expr.cor` and `mval.cor`. Both dataframes have the same number of columns.

```
cr.corr <- sapply(seq(ncol(expr.cor)), function(i) cor(expr.cor[, i], mval.cor[, i], method="spearman"))
```

Traceback:

```
> # normalized matrix for all CRs
> cr.corr <- sapply(seq(ncol(expr.cor)), function(i) cor(expr.cor[, i], mval.cor[, i], method="spearman"))
Error in cor(expr.cor[, i], mval.cor[, i], method = "spearman") :
incompatible dimensions
6.
cor(expr.cor[, i], mval.cor[, i], method = "spearman")
5.
cor(expr.cor[, i], mval.cor[, i], method = "spearman")
4.
FUN(X[[i]], ...)
3.
lapply(X = X, FUN = FUN, ...)
2.
sapply(seq(ncol(expr.cor)), function(i) cor(expr.cor[, i], mval.cor[,
i], method = "spearman"))
1.
sapply(seq(ncol(expr.cor)), function(i) cor(expr.cor[, i], mval.cor[,
i], method
```

= "spearman"))

Input:

```
> dim(expr.cor)
[1] 1118   96
> dim(mval.cor)
[1] 525  96

> dput(expr.cor[1:5,1:5])
structure(list(TCGA.2Z.A9J1.01 = c(9.90686083971644, 7.85453119568792, 
8.14964399360302, 9.770250762185, 8.88994408176988), TCGA.2Z.A9J6.01 = c(11.0827581319988, 
7.20385010562547, 8.87118417188149, 8.94910562068286, 8.7728136979997
), TCGA.2Z.A9J8.01 = c(10.6921133041207, 10.2388193351428, 7.0969238361025, 
7.85207251858217, 11.9555213595621), TCGA.2Z.A9JJ.01 = c(9.20041190448898, 
10.2389705995139, 8.44896824561834, 9.8415805435622, 9.98614168480194
), TCGA.2Z.A9JQ.01 = c(8.22396403818439, 5.07015744755466, 8.19669113197608, 
10.2400835226029, 9.41356636990191)), row.names = c("ENSG00000183044", 
"ENSG00000144452", "ENSG00000154265", "ENSG00000064687", "ENSG00000115657"
), class = "data.frame")

> dput(mval.cor[1:5,1:5])
structure(list(TCGA.2Z.A9J1.01 = c(0.302526294575365, 2.07090116757657, 
-0.42550313021687, -1.11843990054735, 0.88583186907913), TCGA.2Z.A9J6.01 = c(-1.2698574969278, 
2.56530503789387, -0.0344686053337805, -3.11510185770899, 1.10502121263464
), TCGA.2Z.A9J8.01 = c(1.88015522014915, 1.68240596082319, -0.791593211271834, 
-1.0579459033891, 0.303817157212918), TCGA.2Z.A9JJ.01 = c(1.73518494644175, 
0.865407967117148, 1.20981040618737, -2.10671965958959, 0.129470489499436
), TCGA.2Z.A9JQ.01 = c(1.72581755081034, 1.90457672977027, -0.449410970240882, 
-3.27486343531252, 1.10806667324872)), row.names = c("cg00569091", 
"cg03951833", "cg04862289", "cg06626599", "cg09993145"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Your code works fine for me with the example data. Note that you will need the same number of rows in each dataset too for a correlation to be calculated. You might also want to consider `mapply`/`Map` - `mapply(cor, expr.cor, mval.cor, method="spearman")`

Comment: As seen in your `dim()` outputs, you have differing number of rows. The [`cor` documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/cor) directly states that the x and y input vectors should have comparable dimensions